# Seeing the actual error behind ‘An unexpected error has occurred’ in SharePoint 2010

Tags: asp.net

In MOSS 2007, we could update the   tag's callstack attribute to true and then customerrors mode to "Off" to see the actual error behind the 'An unexpected error has occurred' message. Does it apply on SharePoint 2010 as well ? I tried it but I get the following error:

Runtime Error
Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed.

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on the local server machine, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root direc...

Answer (score 2):

If it's a _layouts page you have to change the settings in 14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\web.config as well.

Answer (score 0):

Do you not get a correlation id which you can use to trace the error in the logs?

Comment: I don't think you get the correlation id if something breaks ASP.NET when an unhandled exception hits the worker process - could anyone else confirm?